# How to make a Java program run with my Nvidia GPU

Tags: java, linux, graphics, nvidia, amd-gpu

I just want to run a java program but it is running with my AMD integrated GPU, how can I get this to run with my Nvidia GPU?

Answer (score -1):

On windows, you can try right click -> Run with graphic processor, and than choose which processor you want to use.

Comment: I asked for linux